# What is the pseudonym of this inventor?

Tags: riddle

Thanks to my invention you can:

- Turn energy into something else of value
- Mine without a shovel
- Solve the Byzantine Generals' Problem
- Send money to anyone in the world without the need to involve banks, money transfer or credit card companies

I may be a man a woman or a group of people

Contrary to what you may have read in Newsweek, my real name is not the same as my pseudonym

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really a puzzle. It simply lists out some facts where everything is taken at face value, and does not attempt to hide or obscure the information.

Comment: @manshu The "mine without a shovel" part is pretty a clever obfuscation, otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're talking about the inventor of

> bitcoin, known as *Satoshi Nakamoto*

Turn energy into something else of value
Mine without a shovel

> bitcoin mining makes bitcoins using electricity (and an internet connection)

Solve the Byzantine Generals' Problem

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance#Byzantine_fault_tolerance_in_practice

Send money to anyone in the world without the need to involve banks, money transfer or credit card companies

> the bitcoin network allows people to transfer value over the internet

I may be a man a woman or a group of people

You may actually be Craig Steven Wright, but that's disputed.

Comment: Your Satoshi Nakamoto answer is correct. I personally do not think that Satoshi Nakamoto is Craig Wright but there are still some (small minority)  who do.